# How set $Display variables on Apache2 running on Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, display

I am running Ubuntu 16 server on Azure. I installed Apache2, then I tried to run a Python code that takes a screenshot and save it on the current directory. The code supposed to take a screenshot from my web page. But when I run it, I get this error in the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mss/linux.py", line 132, in __init__
    display = os.environ['DISPLAY'].encode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mss/factory.py", line 34, in mss
    return MSS(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mss/linux.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ScreenShotError('$DISPLAY not set.', locals())
mss.exception.ScreenShotError: ('$DISPLAY not set.', {'display': None, 'self': <mss.linux.MSS object at 0x7f06ce881d30>})
```

I searched a lot and finally I came to know that this error is related to $Display variables in Ubuntu. So how to fix this and allow my code take a screenshot for my web page and save it to my current directory?

Comment: Without graphical enviroment installed, it is not possible to take screenshot of webpage. Do you run that script in console?

Comment: Using Apache2 I run a web page on the internet. On that web page I have a button that takes a screenshot for the page itself. I hope I explained it in a good way!

Comment: @PasiSuominen if I cannot, then what is the solution? How can I do something like this?

Comment: You have a button on the website? In which viewport you take the screenshot then?

Comment: That is correct. The port number is 80. I deployed a web page using Apache2. In my web page there is a button, when you click on the button it should take a screenshot for the whole page and save it to the current directory. It is working perfectly of the local. But I am getting a $Display error when deploying it

Comment: Read my answer below. On your computer, you have viewport where you take screenshot, eg. your webpage is already rendered in screen. Apache does not render your webpage, i have explained in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take a screenshot, you first need a viewport that you can duplicate to picture. If you like to render your webpage directly to a picture, I suggest `pageres` -> https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres. Github page covers the installation. Also firefox could be used with some limitations. There is a good article of command line website screenshotting at booleanworld: [How to Take Screenshots of Webpages from the Command Line](https://www.booleanworld.com/take-screenshots-webpages-command-line/)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and I was able to take a screenshot. But it did not actually solve my problem since I want a screenshot for the whole page but this captured only the html tags without the webcam.

Comment: So do you want to take picture with webcam? Can you explain your problem better? This seems to be an XY problem...

Comment: If you have webcam picture on users browser (sourced from users webcam), you cannot screenshot the page from server side. In that case you need to screenshot on browser side. That is rather complicated but possible with javascript.